# Unable to Display Model Dialog with JQuery-UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm attempting to display a modal dialog as a test run before I try to perform a more difficult task.  However, I seem to be doing something wrong as the code I copied from the [demo site](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/) is not working when I set it up and run it locally.

Here is my source:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                    .html('This dialog will show every time!')
                    .dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        title: 'Basic Dialog'
                });

                $('#opener').click(function() {
                    $dialog.dialog('open');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="opener">Press</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

So far, I have primarily been thinking the problem may have been a relative path problem with the way I'm bringing in the external libraries.  But I tried variations, and nothing changed.

I am still new to Javascript, so I may be doing some very noob-ish here.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things you could try firstly add a link tag for the css

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

secondly make sure that you have the dialog component selected in your custom ui js package.

Comment: +1 for mentioning css. Adding CSS should work Jason.It did for me

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $dialog = $('<div></div>').appendTo(document.body);
});
```